# How can I put a logo in a RMarkdown Document HTML

Tags: html, r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am having an issue trying to put a logo at the header of my RMarkdown document.

This is what I have

```
---
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css">

body, td {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Gills Sans TM";
}
code.r{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Gills Sans TM";
}
pre {
  font-size: 12px
  font-family: "Gills Sans TM";
}
</style>
```

But i do not find how can I add a logo at the top-right

Comment: I posted it as an answer, so you can check it and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
<img src="mylogo.png" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;" />
```

Comment: I am kind of lost, where should I put this in the Rmd file?

Comment: Below the 2nd `---` @NicolasMolano